# Producer/consumer with bounded buffer

Tags: c, semaphore, grand-central-dispatch, consumer

Could someone check my code and tell me if I am on the right track.. It seems like I am a bit lost.. if you see my errors, please let me know them..

What I am trying to do is to solve bounded buffer using my own semaphores as well as GCD.

Thanks in advance..

sema.c

```
void procure( Semaphore *semaphore ) {

        pthread_mutex_lock(semaphore->mutex1);

        while(semaphore->value <= 0)
                pthread_cond_wait(&semaphore->condition, semaphore->mutex1);


        semaphore->value--;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(semaphore->mutex1);


}

void vacate( Semaphore *semaphore ) {

        pthread_mutex_lock(semaphore->mutex1);
        semaphore->value++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&semaphore->condition);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(semaphore->mutex1);        
}


void init ( Semaphore *semaphore ){

        semaphore->value = 1;

        pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
        semaphore->mutex1 = &myMutex;
        pthread_mutex_init( semaphore->mutex1, NULL);



}

void destroy ( Semaphore *semaphore ) {

        pthread_mutex_destroy(semaphore->mutex1);


}
```

and main.c

```
struct variables {

        Semaphore *sem;

};

struct variables vars;

void constructer (int *buffer, int *in, int *out) {

        init(vars.sem);

}


void deconstructer () {

        destroy(vars.sem);

}



int rand_num_gen() {
        uint_fast16_t buffer;
        int file;
        int *rand;

        file = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);


        while( 1 ) {

                read(file, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));

                printf("16 bit number: %hu\n", buffer );

                *rand = (int) buffer;

                close(file);


                break;
        }

        return *rand;
}


void put_buffer( int* buffer, int* in, int* out ) {

        buffer[*in] = rand_num_gen();    // produce

        procure(vars.sem);                // wait here
                *in = (*in + 1) % BUF_SIZE;
        vacate(vars.sem);

}

void get_buffer( int* buffer, int* in, int* out ) {

        int value;  

        procure(vars.sem);
                value = buffer[*out];  
        vacate(vars.sem);

        *out = (*out + 1) % BUF_SIZE;

}

int main (void) {


        int *in, *out, *buffer;     

        constructer(buffer, in, out);        



        dispatch_queue_t producer, consumer;    

        producer = dispatch_queue_create("put_buffer", NULL);
        consumer = dispatch_queue_create("get_buffer", NULL);



        dispatch_async(producer,
                       ^{
                               int i;
                               do
                               {
                                        put_buffer( buffer, in, out );


                                       dispatch_async(consumer,
                                                      ^{
                                                              get_buffer( buffer, in, out );

                                                              if (i == RUN_LENGTH) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                                                      });
                               }
                               while (i < RUN_LENGTH);             
                       });

        dispatch_main();                

        deconstructer();

        exit (0);
}
```

Comment: I receive bad access here `buffer[*in] = rand_num_gen();` how can I fix it?

Comment: Which language is that? C doesn't have a lambda (`^`) operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a bug. In the `init` function you assign the address of a local variable to `semaphore->mutex1`, and when the function returns this address will be invalid. Later you still use this address, so this leads to *undefined behavior*.

You must either allocate the memory for the mutex directly in the semaphore (without a pointer) or allocate the memory via `malloc`.

**Update:**

Your program has so many bugs that you should definitely pick an easier topic to learn the basic concepts about memory management, how to allocate, use and reference a buffer, do proper error handling, etc. Here is a slightly edited version of your code. It still won't work, but probably has some ideas that you should follow.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void procure(Semaphore *semaphore) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(semaphore->mutex1);

  while (semaphore->value <= 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&semaphore->condition, semaphore->mutex1);

  semaphore->value--;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(semaphore->mutex1);
}

void vacate(Semaphore *semaphore) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(semaphore->mutex1);
  semaphore->value++;
  pthread_cond_signal(&semaphore->condition);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(semaphore->mutex1);  
}

struct variables {
  mutex_t sem_mutex;
  Semaphore sem;
};

struct variables vars;

void constructor(int *buffer, int *in, int *out) {
  vars.sem.value = 1;
  vars.sem.mutex1 = &vars.sem_mutex;
  pthread_mutex_init(vars.sem.mutex1, NULL);
}

void deconstructor() {
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&semaphore->mutex1);
}

int rand_num_gen() {
  const char *randomfile = "/dev/random";
  unsigned char buffer[2]; // Changed: always treat files as byte sequences.
  FILE *f = fopen(randomfile, "rb");
  // Changed: using stdio instead of raw POSIX file access,
  // since the API is much simpler; you don't have to care
  // about interrupting signals or partial reads.

  if (f == NULL) { // Added: error handling
    fprintf(stderr, "E: cannot open %s\n", randomfile);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (fread(buffer, 1, 2, f) != 2) { // Added: error handling
    fprintf(stderr, "E: cannot read from %s\n", randomfile);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  fclose(f);
  int number = (buffer[0] << CHAR_BIT) | buffer[1];
  // Changed: be independent of the endianness of the system.
  // This doesn't matter for random number generators but is
  // still an important coding style.
  printf("DEBUG: random number: %x\n", (unsigned int) number);
  return number;
}

void put_buffer( int* buffer, int* in, int* out ) {
  buffer[*in] = rand_num_gen();    // produce
  procure(&vars.sem);    // wait here
  *in = (*in + 1) % BUF_SIZE;
  vacate(&vars.sem);
}

void get_buffer( int* buffer, int* in, int* out ) {
  int value;  
  procure(&vars.sem);
  value = buffer[*out];  
  vacate(&vars.sem);
  *out = (*out + 1) % BUF_SIZE;
}

int main (void) {
  int inindex = 0, outindex = 0;
  int buffer[BUF_SIZE];

  constructor(buffer, &inindex, &outindex);
  // Changed: provided an actual buffer and actual variables
  // for the indices into the buffer.
  dispatch_queue_t producer, consumer;    
  producer = dispatch_queue_create("put_buffer", NULL);
  consumer = dispatch_queue_create("get_buffer", NULL);

  dispatch_async(producer, ^{
    int i;
    do {
      put_buffer(buffer, &inindex, &outindex);
      dispatch_async(consumer, ^{
        get_buffer(buffer, &inindex, &outindex);
        if (i == RUN_LENGTH) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      });
    } while (i < RUN_LENGTH);
  });

  dispatch_main();    
  deconstructor();
  exit (0);
}
```

As I said, I didn't catch all the bugs.

Comment: i wasnt calling the constructer and deconstructer functions.. i fixed it but couldnt see any differences

Comment: You never initialize the `in` variable. I think you want to declare both `in` and `out` as int in = 0,out = 0; and pass the address of them to your functions.